# How to properly handle locale change at runtime with Android 24+ multi window mode?

Tags: android, multi-window

Just out of curiosity: how should I handle locale change in the phone's setting menu if user use the multi window mode to open my app and the settings side by side? How can I notify all the string resources and stuff change accordingly, and how to I trigger some logic to run (e.g. API call requires locale so I have to re-fetch everything)? Right now I am using a broadcast receiver that triggers `System.exit(0);` to launch the whole app again. But obviously this does not translate well into multi window mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A locale change is a configuration change, just like orientation. If you want to handle it manually, you can have your activity handle it using `android:configChanges="locale"` attribute. You can get the locale from the Configuration in `onConfigurationChanged()` using `getLocales().get(0)`, compare it with current locale and handle the change when detected.

Else, I expect your activity to be recreated and you can handle the locale for a new activity in a single uniform fashion.